# execute pdo insert excluding certain parameters

Tags: php, sql, pdo, db2

My SELECT queries are getting everything appropriately, but my insert fails because my parameter values contain too many for the insert (frame2,cover2,color2, etc.)

I need the extra parameters for my 2nd select, but I don't need them for the insert.

Is there a way to execute my insert and say "execute on $salesValues without :frame2, :cover2, :color2, :frame3, :cover3, :color3"

```
$selectPlacements = "
    SELECT DISTINCT
        sku_id, s.frame as frame, sg.group_code as group_code, sg.name as group_name, s.cover1 as cover, s.color1 as color, dealer_id, sales_rep as repNum, count(*) as placements
    FROM place p
    inner join skus s 
    on p.sku_id = s.id
    inner join sku_groups sg 
    on sg.id = s.sku_group_id
    where p.expire_date > curdate()
    group by sku_id, s.frame, dealer_id
    ;
";

try {
    $placementCheck = $MysqlConn->prepare($selectPlacements);
    $detailRslt = $placementCheck->execute();

     while ($placementRow = $placementCheck->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        print_r($placementRow); //This prints the array I need

        $salesValues = [
        ":dealer_id" => $placementRow["dealer_id"],
    ":frame" => $placementRow["frame"],
    ":cover" => $placementRow["cover"],
    ":color" => $placementRow["color"],
    ":frame2" => $placementRow["frame"],
    ":cover2" => $placementRow["cover"],
    ":color2" => $placementRow["color"],
    ":frame3" => $placementRow["frame"],
    ":cover3" => $placementRow["cover"],
    ":color3" => $placementRow["color"],
    ":group_code" => $placementRow["group_code"],
    ":group_name" => $placementRow["group_name"],
    ":placements" => $placementRow["placements"],
    ":repNum" => $placementRow["repNum"],
        ];

        $insertSales = "
            MERGE INTO Tmetrics AS T
                USING (VALUES (
                    CAST(:dealer_id as CHAR(10)),
                    CAST(:frame as CHAR(10)),
                    CAST(:cover as CHAR(10)),
                    CAST(:color as CHAR(10)),
                    CAST(:group_code as CHAR(10)),
                    CAST(:group_name as CHAR(25)),
                    CAST(:sales180Cust as CHAR(10)),
                    CAST(:velocityCust as CHAR(10)),
                    CAST(:repnum as CHAR(10)),
                    CAST(:sales180Rep as CHAR(10)),
                    CAST(:velocityRep as CHAR(10)),
                    CAST(:sales180Comp as CHAR(10)),
                    CAST(:velocityComp as CHAR(10)),
                    CAST(:placements as CHAR(10))
                    )
                )

            AS S(dealer, frame, cover, color, groupnum, groupname, last180days_sales,velocity,repnumber,last180_rep,velocityrep,last180company,velocitycompany,placements)
            ON S.dealer = T.dealer and S.frame = T.frame and S.cover = T.cover and S.color = T.color
            WHEN MATCHED
                THEN UPDATE SET last180days_sales = S.last180days_sales, velocity = S.velocity, repnumber = S.repnumber, last180_rep = S.last180_rep, velocityrep = S.velocityrep, last180company = S.last180company, velocitycompany = S.velocitycompany
             WHEN NOT MATCHED
                THEN INSERT VALUES(S.dealer, s.frame, s.cover, s.color, s.groupnum, s.groupname, s.last180days_sales,s.velocity,s.repnumber,s.last180_rep,s.velocityrep,s.last180company,s.velocitycompany,s.placements)
        ";
      try{

                $velocityExecution = $velocityInsertPrep->execute($salesValues);

            }catch(PDOException $ex){

                echo "INSERT_FAILED: " .$ex->getMessage();

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to pass values to `PDOStatement::execute()` and tell PDO not to use them, but you can easily just not pass those values to `execute()` to begin with, using pure PHP `array_diff_key()`:

```
// Note, the actual values can be anything. The keys just need to be set.
$ignores = [
    'frame2' => false,
    'cover2' => false,
    'color2' => false,
]; 

$velocityExecution = $velocityInsertPrep->execute(array_diff_key($salesValues, $ignores));
```